# Не открывается проект Laravel в браузере под Windows7

Tags: laravel, windows-7, composer, xampp

Установил Laravel на Windows7 через Composer с Xampp
Создал новый проект Laravel "my_project1" командой "laravel new my_project1" в папке "c:\My_laravel_projecs"

Пытаюсь открыть проект в браузере:
http://localhost/my_project1/public/ - выдает ошибку апача "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server."
http://localhost/my_project1/ - выдает ошибку апача "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server."

ок, запускаю в консоли "php artisan serve"
выдает: "Starting Laravel development server: [http://127.0.0.1:8000"](http://127.0.0.1:8000%22)

запускаю так:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_project1/public/ - теперь выдает ошибку Laravel "404 | NOT FOUND"
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_project1/ - теперь выдает ошибку Laravel "404 | NOT FOUND"
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ - выводит страницу с красными логотипом и надписью Laravel

Подскажите, как мне запустить проект из папки c:\My_laravel_projecs\my_project1"?

Comment: Что выдает по `http://127.0.0.1:8000` после `php artisan serve`?

Comment: страница с красным логотипом и надписью это и есть ваш проект

Comment: вы просто ничего ещё не поменяли, это страница по умолчанию

Comment: А что вы хотели чтобы там было? Почему вы решили что это некорректное поведение? Почему вы начали изучать laravel раньше чем php?